# product of a module by an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, definition

I have a ring $R$, an ideal $I$ of $R$ and an $R$-module $M$. How does one define $IM$. Is it the set $\{im\ \vert\ i\in I, m\in M\}$ or is it the smallest module containing these elements?

Comment: According to [this website](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/de/AGR/CommutativeAlgebra/pp289-314.pdf) (first page), it is indeed the latter one (the module generated by these elements).

Comment: Is multiplication in $R$ commutative? If not then you need to be more careful about how things are defined (left/right/two-sided stuff). You want a submodule, and the mere set of products $im$ is usually not a submodule, but the set of *finite sums* $i_1m_1+\ldots+i_km_k$ is a submodule of $M$ if $R$ is commutative, so that set is defined to be $IM$. Note: if $I = (x)$ is a principal ideal then $IM = xM = \{xm : m \in M\}$.

Comment: Note the *set* $\{im \ | \ i \in I, m \in M\}$ is usually not closed under addition and hence is not a module.  For example if you look at the polynomial ring $P = \mathbb R[w, x, y, z]$ and $I = (w, x)$ and $M = (y, z)$ (an ideal treated as a submodule of the free module $P$) then $wy$ and $xz$ are of the required form but $wy + xz$ is an irreducible polynomial so it can only be written as a product if one of the two elements is a unit, and $I$ and $M$ don't contain units so $wy + xz$ is not an element of the form $im$.

Comment: So the correct definition of $IM$ is the one given by Narcissus jewel in their answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is the structure $IM$ for $I$ an ideal and $M$ a module?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90283/what-exactly-is-the-structure-im-for-i-an-ideal-and-m-a-module)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $R$ is commutative, then we can proceed as in A&M page 19.

Let $I\subset R$ be an ideal, and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Then, $IM$ is the set of all finite sums $\sum r_ix_i$ where $r_i\in I$ and $x_i\in M$. This is of course a submodule of $M$.

Comment: What is A&M? Could you give the complete title?

Comment: @vesszabo Atiyah and Macdonald, Introduction to Commutative Algebra, 1969. The relevant text appears in the second last paragraph (i.e. the paragraph under Proposition 2.1).

Comment: A (currently working) link to the text is: https://wstein.org/edu/Fall2003/252/references/Atiyah-MacDonald/Atiyah-McDonald-Commutative_Algebra.pdf