# How does an element in $I^n(R/J)$ looks like if $R$ is a ring and $I,J$ are ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, quotient-spaces

Let $R$ be a ring, $I$, $J$ ideals then how does an element of $I^n(R/J)$ looks like. I know that an element of $I^n$ is of the form $(x_1x_2...x_n)$ for $x_i\in I$ but then do I multiply it with $r+J$ for some $r\in R$?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Note that $R/J$ is an $R$-module, and the structure of an ideal times an $R$-module is described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90283/what-exactly-is-the-structure-im-for-i-an-ideal-and-m-a-module in short, it's all finite sums of elements of $I^n$ times elements of $R/J$.

Comment: You simply add some element of $J$ to it, namely $I^n(R/J)$ is the coset $\{x_1x_2\cdots x_n + J: x_i \in R\}$ of $R/J$.

Comment: @WhatsUp is it also true if I say $(x_1\cdot \cdot \cdot x_n)+J$? or is this something different

Comment: Yes it's the same. I omitted $()$ because $\cdot$ has higher priority than $+$.

Comment: @WhatsUp sorry but I mean the () because of ideal generating by $x_1\cdot \cdot \cdot x_n$ not because of "normal" brackets

Comment: An element of $I^n$ is a *sum* of such products.

Comment: @Randall sorry I'm somehow a bit lost. So $I^n=\{r_1x_1\cdot \cdot \cdot x_n+r_2x_1\cdot \cdot \cdot x_n...:r_i\in R, x_i\in I\}$?

Comment: $I^n$ is the product of $I$ with itself $n$ times (the ideal product, not the cartesian product). See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290229/explaining-the-product-of-two-ideals

Comment: The reason it's the set of *sums* of products of elements is so that the resulting object $I^n$ is actually an ideal: it needs to be closed under addition.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow so $I^n=\left\{\sum_{j=1} x_{i_1}y_{i_2}...z_{i_n}\right\}$ where the sum needs to be finite. Is this true?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow sorry I'm really lost right now. Could you please explain why WhatsUp only wrote $x_1\cdot \cdot \cdot x_n$ and not as a sum like you are saying

Comment: I'm not sure. $I^n$ is supposed to be the ideal generated by all elements of the form $x_1\cdots x_n$ where each $x_i\in I$. Or in otherwords, the set of all sums of elements of that form just like you wrote in your previous comment. See https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Product_of_ideals for some equivalent definitions.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow okey thanks I see this now but what I still do not see is why an element in $I^n(R/J)$ is $(x_1\cdot \cdot \cdot x_n) +J$? Could you also explain me this?

Comment: If you click the link I posted in my first comment up at the top, it will describe what the elements look like. In summary, $I^n(R/J)$ is the set of all finite sums of the form $a_1m_1+\ldots+a_km_k$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $a_i\in I^n$ and $m_i\in R/J$. This is a special case of "ideal times module". Do you know about modules? You don't *need* to know about modules to understand this construction, but it may help.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow yes I know about modules I'm only a bit confused since formally these $a_i$ would also be sums so we would have like the sum of sums right? That's what confuses me

Comment: Yep, in this case it's like you have sums of sums. Each $a_i$ can be written as a sum, and the elements $a_1m_1+\ldots+a_km_k\in I^n(R/J)$ are also sums. So for example, an element of $I^n(R/J)$ might look like $(x_1\cdots x_n+y_1\cdots y_n)(r_1+J)+z_1\cdots z_n(r_2+J)$ where the $x_i,y_i,z_i\in I$ and the $r_1,r_2\in R$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Ah okey but this is completely useless if I want to who's that $I^n(R/J)=(I/J)^n$ right? because there would be too many indexes

Comment: @MichaelMorrow so would it be easier to calculate with $(x_1\cdot \cdot \cdot x_n)+J$?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow so I think I should get something like  $(x_1...x_n)+J=(x_1+J)...(x_n+J)$ but I don't see what property I need to use