# Multiplication of an ideal with a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $p$ be an ideal of a ring $R$. Is it then true that the multiplication of $p$ with $R$, i.e. $pR$ is defined as $\{mr:m\in p, r\in R\}$ since $p\subset R$ and we use the normal multiplication $f:R\times R\rightarrow R$ and restrict this to $p\times R\rightarrow R$. So like we use the map $f|_{p\times R}$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, the proper way is to think of it as $\sum_i r_i p_i$ where $r_i \in R$ and $p_i \in p$.  This is true since your ideal may not be generated by a single element (principal ideals are).

Comment: That is the definition of multiplication of two ideals, $R$ happens to be an ideal.  Whenever you see $IJ$ for two ideals, they mean finite sums of linear combinations.

Comment: @AbstractSpaceCrack okey so it is generated by $mr$?

Comment: We don't know what the ideal is generated by.  Could be anything

Comment: @AbstractSpaceCrack ah okey. But I can say that $pR=\langle mr; m\in p, r\in R\rangle$ where $\langle, \rangle$ means generated.

Comment: If your ideal is defined to be $bR$ for some $b\in R$, then your ideal by definition is generated by $b$.  But your ideal could be $aR + bR$ for example.

Comment: If $1 \in R$ ie. the ring is unital, then $pR = p$, but yeah I think you could say that it's generated as an abelian group that way, which is a more general construction than ideal.

Comment: @AbstractSpaceCrack ah okey but then I understood it correctly that the definition of the product of two ideals or the product of a ideal with a ring or even the product with an ideal and an $R$-module are all defined in the "same" way with this set of finite sums except that the element comes from different sources

Comment: Yes, that's true.  Here is more about $IM$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90283/what-exactly-is-the-structure-im-for-i-an-ideal-and-m-a-module

Comment: @AbstractSpaceCrack perfect thanks

Comment: You're welcome, mon :)

Comment: @AbstractSpaceCrack sorry for the stupid question but it seems that you really like algebra and you know how it works. Is there like a possibility to ask questions directly to you? Because I really like and understand your answers. So I mean do you have like a public chatroom here?